# Argon in head space and storage temp

Tags: storage, cold

I've been a wine maker and grower for 10+ years and now diving into home beer making which is a lot of fun and gives MUCH faster returns on enjoyment.  I have seen where some folks recommend filling the head space in the conditioning carboy (secondary) with CO2.  In wine making argon is preferred (and I have it).

Any comments about using this to spurge air out of the secondary?

Also, I have a wine lab/cellar that I keep around 64°F (17°C).  Is that a good environment for conditioning or too cold?

Thanks!
Ric

Answer (score 2):

**If you have Argon, you can used it, however I do not think it is necessary**, unless you have a lot of free space, like a half full carboy.  Good, sanitation is much more important than air exposure.

Mainly, because beer will not age as long as wine in a carboy, the process being shorter.
I find beer much more resistent to air exposure compared to wine (my opinion).
I made over 35 batches so far (4-5 gallons each) and I never spoiled a batch due to air exposition (fingers crossed).

Regarding the temperature, to **bottle condition** (bottle fermentation), it will depend on your yeast, the colder the longer it will take to carbonate, but it should work.

For **storage afterwards**, it's ok to store for less than 6 months in bottles at that temperature (depends on the type of beer as well).  The hotter, the faster your beer will age.  For instance, your beer might be perfect after 2 months at that temperature or exactly the same after 4 months in a fridge.  So to age beer for a longer period of time, you should find colder place.  Usually the malt flavour dissappears first, then hops right after, until eventually it will become too bland to enjoy.

Comment: Thanks Philippe!